# Unable to export container image vulnerabilities from GCR?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I am using GCR to host container images and using a native scanner to scan for vulnerabilities.

Is there a way I can export container registry vulnerabilities into CSV format from GUI/API?

I don't see anything at the GUI for export. Without the export feature, it's difficult to share findings to the team for the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to get the list(or occurence) of vulnerabilities using Container analysis API.

The code that is used to retrieve the list is [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/2329466637798630851fb70f7a157b8d5edecb6c/container_registry/container_analysis/samples.py#L334)

The details of the usage of API and methods is in [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/tutorial-vulnerability-scan)(which i am assuming you would have gone through)

Based on the list you can export it to a flat file in GCS or Pub/Sub topic, for which you will have to write extra logic